# PregMatch on 3 digits with a dot

Tags: php, preg-match

I have numbers like theses:

> 1.80
>   2.75
>   @1.55

Theses numbers are in strings and I'm trying to get them throught preg_match. At this time I have this:

```
$pattern = '/ [0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}/';  
$result = preg_match($pattern, $feed, $matches);
```

This works pretty well but I need more precision on my preg_match and I didn't found a solution.
With this pattern, numbers like 1.556 will be found. I don't want this, my numbers length will be 4 chars. dot included.

Also, here I am not able to catch the numbers starting by a @, only a space. How can I do this?

```
$result = preg_match($pattern, 'test 1.556 red @1.62 blue 2.33 ?', $matches);
```

Here the results needed are 1.62 and 2.33

Comment: Add range of digits you want. For minimum 2 and maximum 3 floating point digits use `[0-9]{2,3}`

Comment: [Add `\b at the end`](http://rubular.com/r/rlNZfkSNYS)?

Comment: @PeeHaa if you wanna post it as an anwer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following pattern will match all numbers in the format of `#.##` with an optional leading space or at sign.

```
[ @]?(\d{1}\.\d{2})\b
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/eB4bL5

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to regular expressions, PHP-[Sanitization](http://www.php.net/manual/de/filter.filters.sanitize.php)-[Filters](http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.filter.php):

```
$array = explode(' ', 'test 1.556 red @1.62 blue 2.33 ?');

$result = filter_var_array(
    array(
        'convert' => $array
    ), 
    array(
        'convert' => array(
            'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 
            'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION | FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY
        )
    )
);

var_dump(array_filter(array_map('floatval', $result['convert'])));
```

results in:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  float(1.556)
  [3]=>
  float(1.62)
  [5]=>
  float(2.33)
}
```

Comment: Too much complicated for my need I think.. Btw thanks for your participation.

Comment: Yes, but filters a bit more flexible versus your (defined) regex. FLOAT-Filters didn't care about digit-counts, only valid floats are sanitized, your regex wouldn't match any possible float-definition ( positive or negative, common or scientific spelled ). Anyway, it's an alternative, regex is faster on large texts and should be prefered. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it up to 4 precision and the @ to be catched That is what you need

```
$pattern = '/ @*([0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2})\b /';
```

Comment: $pattern = '/ @*[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2,4}/';
$result = preg_match($pattern, 'test 1.556 red @1.55 blue 2.33 ?', $matches);
var_dump($matches);

You get the result that I don't want.

Comment: Yep, I edited the first post with a little explanation at the end.

Comment: try that @*([0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2})\b :)

Comment: '/[0-9]{1}\.[0-9]{2}\b/' is the good one. We've missed to use preg_match_all also. Try with this sentence: `code`'test 1.556 red @1.65 blue 5.22 on 4.32 @5.12 ?'`code`

Comment: I see I thought you want the numbers with the @ in front of them anyway I am glad you have found the solution

Comment: Thanks also for participation.